# better way to resize image?

Tags: ipad, image-processing, opengl-es

Im using CGBitmapContextCreate to read the data from a png file.
I then resize the image with a couple of loops to fit the OpenGL ES image size criteria.

I was wondering if there is a better way to this.

Basically what I do now is have a nested loop like:

```
for(i<newHeight){
   for(j<newWidth){
      copy image data
   }
}
```

For instance can I pass the new sizes to the CGBitmapContextCreate when reading the data?

Comment: So you want to resize the image to the next power of 2? Are you looking for the best rescaling algorithm or the easiest way to do this  in openglES?

Answer (score 0):

A nice extension: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Comment: Although that seems useful it doesint quite seem to be what im looking for.
Basically I have images of random size (ex:120x632) and I need to increase the sizes through coding to become the sizes required for OpenGL(in this case 128x1024), however I still draw the images with the original dimensions.